# Get a hidden grid view column, cell value on a selected row c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a client id column in my grid view, which i would prefer to stay hidden or un-editable.

when the row of the gridview is being updated i would like to check if the value of a field is being changed to a certain value so i can time stamp in my database.

Here is a copy of my function.

```
 protected void gridStock_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        String anotherUpdatedItem = e.NewValues[8].ToString();
        string oldValue = e.OldValues[7].ToString();

        string idValue = gridStock.DataKeys[0].Values["StockID"].ToString();

        anotherUpdatedItem.ToString();

        if (anotherUpdatedItem == "True" && oldValue != "True")
        {
            string date = DateTime.Today.ToString();

            String str = "UPDATE Stock SET [DateSold]=@todaysDate WHERE StockID=@id";

            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
            xp.Parameters.Add("@todaysDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
            xp.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idValue;

            vid.Open();

            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "ClientID");

            vid.Close();
        }
    }
```

As you can see i have added a datakey to the gridview, this also works but it only retrieves index 0 point. I need to get the stockid value of the row which has been clicked on to be able to pass it through my sql query.

Could any one please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the Datakey value by using the current row's index. You can use `e.RowIndex` for this purpose. Here is what you need:

```
string idValue = gridStock.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["StockID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this method to work you'd need to use the index of the selected row.

```
string idValue = gridStock.DataKeys[gridStock.SelectedIndex].Values["StockID"].ToString();
```